# Compression filter with JSON RESTful services, is it worth it?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, compression

How large would a message have to be to be worth compressing the content in RESTful API JSON responses? It is fairly easy to add a compression filter like GZipOutputStream.  Under what conditions would I see a reduced response time on the client side?  Are there any other pros and cons of compressing the responses?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: To save bandwidth and decrease response times.

Comment: How would doing extra work on both the server and the client to compress/decompress the response *decrease* response times?

Comment: When the time needed to transfer the compressed data over the network is significantly less that the time needed to transfer the un-compressed data because of the size difference?

Comment: How big are your JSON payloads?

Comment: Good question, not more than one megabyte on average.

Comment: I personally wouldn't bother then, but that's me

Comment: I reworded the question to put add in size considerations, response time metric, and asking for additional pros and cons.  It would be useful to mention if there is a time constraint on the current processing